# Copy a file and keep the same timestamp of the original file

Tags: files, cp, timestamp

I need to a copy file and after that I need to change the timestamp attributes as the original file. How can I do it with the terminal or any other way?

Comment: Why *"after that"*, specifically? you can preserve the timestamp (and other attributes) *during* copying by using the `-p` or `--preserve=` option e.g. `cp -p oldfile newfile`

Comment: @steeldriver Technically cp itself also does it afterwards. Please make `cp --preserve=timestamps`  an answer

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you want to preserve the original timestamps, use

```
$ touch -r <original_file> <new_file>
```

This copies the timestamps from another file.

See this blog post for more: [Fake File Access, Modify and Change TimeStamps](https://www.shellhacks.com/fake-file-access-modify-change-timestamps-linux/)

Comment: Will this work for folders, or all files in a folder?

Comment: Helpful when you left `-p` option out of a `cp`, thanks.

Answer (score 174):

You can preserve the timestamp of the original file when copying using `cp` by adding the `-p` or `--preserve` option:

> ```
>    -p     same as --preserve=mode,ownership,timestamps
>
>    --preserve[=ATTR_LIST]
>           preserve the specified attributes (default: mode,ownership,time‐
>           stamps), if  possible  additional  attributes:  context,  links,
>           xattr, all
> ```

So to preserve only the timestamp

```
cp --preserve=timestamps oldfile newfile
```

or to preserve mode and ownership as well

```
cp --preserve oldfile newfile
```

or

```
cp -p oldfile newfile
```

Additional options are available for recursive copying - a common one is `cp -a` (`cp --archive`) which additionally preserves symbolic links.

Comment: Surprisingly, this did not work on macOS when copying from a FAT32 partition to an exFAT partition.

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer. It solves the problem with one command which I think is what the OP was really after. It is also well explained.

Comment: On a Mac, use gcp (GNU cp from coreutils, as in `brew install coreutils`)

Answer (score 2):

If for instance you forgot the cp -p parameter and need to replace timestamps with their originals recursively without recopying all the files. Here is what worked for me:

```
find /Destination -exec bash -c 'touch -r "${0/Destination/Source}" "$0"' {} \;
```

This assumes a duplicate file/ folder tree of Source: `/Source` and Destination: `/Destination`

1. `find` searches the Destination for all files & dirs (which need timestamps) and `-exec ... {}` runs a command for each result.
2. `bash -c ' ... '` executes a shell command using bash.
3. `$0` holds the find result.
4. `touch -r {timestamped_file} {file_to_stamp}` uses a bash replace command `${string/search/replace}` to set timestamp source appropriately.
5. the Source and Destination directories are quoted to handle dirs with spaces.