# How can I copy a folder without altering their original dates of creation?

Tags: command-line

I found an old archive filled with old folders on my pc.
I would like to know how to make a copy of this archive, but keeping everything intact, including their date of creation

Comment: Note that most Linux filesystems don't store dates of creation — the best you can have is date of last modification.

Comment: @Ruslan most do, it's just hasn't been accessible via kernel APIs until the statx call got merged. And even then, I don't think the creation time can be set manually.

Comment: @muru so, we can't actually copy a file preserving its date of creation in the copy, can we? If we can't, then this attribute is useless: it's then the date of creation of the inode, not of the document.

Comment: This question is NOT a duplicate as @muru indicated, because the other question do not address this problem the ctime attribute. Please do not forget that this question is searched by other people who do not make assumptions about what the asking person really wanted, but are only interested in what the question asks. By the way, the question was addressed here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126992/setting-changing-the-ctime-or-change-time-attribute-on-a-file/17066309#17066309

Answer (score 10):

Read `man cp`, and, in addition to the `--recursive` switch use one of:

```
   -p     same as --preserve=mode,ownership,timestamps

   --preserve[=ATTR_LIST]
          preserve the specified attributes (default: mode,ownership,timestamps), if possible
          additional attributes: context, links, xattr, all
```

Comment: This will not preserve the original creation time (in fact, the last status change time). Only the last modification time will be preserved.

Answer (score 9):

As indicated in the other answers, you need to use the terminal if you want to preserve every file attribute. However, I would suggest to use the `-a` (`--archive`) option with the `cp` command, which is specifically aimed at creating an identical archive copy.

```
cp -a <source> <destination>
```

The same can be achieved with the `rsync` utility, the local and remote file copy tool that may perform faster than `cp`. It also uses the option `-a` for the same purpose.

```
rsync -a <source> <destination>
```

*For example*, to copy a folder Archive in your home folder to an external USB drive mounted under `/media/$USER/USB_drive`:

```
cp -a /home/$USER/Archive /media/$USER/USB_drive/
```

or

```
rsync  -a /home/$USER/Archive /media/$USER/USB_drive/
```

- Both commands will create a folder `Archive` containing all your subfolders and files in the existing destination folder `/media/$USER/USB_drive/`.
- You can find where your USB drive is mounted in the output of the command `mount | grep /media`
- You can leave `$USER` in place if it is for your current user. This variable is automatically substituted by your login name.

Comment: **Beware:** if you use tab completion, you may unthinkingly leave a trailing slash on the source directory, which will do [*quite* a different action](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/384837/135943).  (Specifically, it would copy all the *contents* of `/home/$USER/Archive/` into `/media/$USER/USB_drive/` rather than making a new subdirectory.)  The commands as shown are correct; I just want to emphasize that adding a trailing slash to the source is *not* equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo cp -rp /home/my_home /media/backup/my_home
```

Or

```
sudo cp -a /home/my_home /media/backup/my_home
```

This should do it.

- `-r` is recursive
- `-p` is preserve-mode

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way to get or set the creation time of a file in Linux. If that absolutely must be preserved, for which I don't see much point, you can fake the system time (using, for example, the aptly named [`faketime`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/faketime.1.html) command) when copying the files, but you'd need to copy each entry individually, so that the time can be set for each file correctly. Even then, there might be some inaccuracy. Since [getting the creation time](https://askubuntu.com/q/470134/158442) itself is a chore, and since time can be faked pretty easily, but probably not exactly, there really isn't much point to doing so, however.

Comment: I think the OP just wants to have the output of `ls -l` show the same timestamps for source and target (without actually knowing or being interested in what those timestamps precisely refer to). Yet +1 for explaining the background.

Comment: @PerlDuck in that case it would be a dupe of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1040885/copy-file-and-keep-same-timestamp-of-original-file or other such questions

Comment: Which I think it is.

Comment: There is certainly a point of doing so for backup and restore purposes, of if you want to transfer a whole hierarchy to another file system without loosing that info.
And by the way, to avoid the precision problem you might want to proceed in two steps : 1/ copy the filesystem, 2/ change the status file per file with faketime.

Comment: however for access  https://askubuntu.com/questions/62492/how-can-i-change-the-date-modified-created-of-a-file ...

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers are correct, you may want to add the file to **.zip** archive (maybe in addition to plain copy if it's not huge), as it will preserve timestamps better in the long term (given enough time, you data will be copied around to various storage media, restored from backups, put to and from the cloud etc. and file metadata like timestamps will eventually be lost. Being inside ZIP archive will protect it.)

Answer (score 0):

simply copying an archive file won't change the created dates of the files/folders in the archive

Comment: Likely the OP is referring to an old archive folder, not to an archive file